# Parent-child relationship in JPA error when inserting more than one child

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, primefaces, openjpa, apache-tomee

I am developing a file management application under JSF/Primefaces and Tomee/OpenJPA.
I am having a weird bug that is getting me crazy !

So here is my Entity :

```
   @Entity
        public class MyBoxFile implements Serializable {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
            private int id;

            private String name;

            private String fileType;   

            @Lob
            @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=true)
            @Column(nullable = true, length=2000000000)
            private byte[] file;    

            @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
            private MyBoxUser owner;    

            @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
            @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
            private MyBoxFile parent;    

            @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
            private List<MyBoxFile> childs = new LinkedList<>();

            //Getters & Setters ..
        }
```

It represent files and directories (depending on `fileType`). A directory could have children.
I am creating the database from my entities. To retrieve all the directories of the database I use this code:

```
public List<MyBoxFile> findAllUsersDirs(MyBoxUser owner) {
    owner = em.find(MyBoxUser.class, owner.getLogin());
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<MyBoxFile> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(MyBoxFile.class);
    Root<MyBoxFile> from = criteriaQuery.from(MyBoxFile.class);
    criteriaQuery.where(
        criteriaBuilder.and(
                       criteriaBuilder.equal(from.get(MyBoxFile_.owner), owner),

                     criteriaBuilder.equal(from.get(MyBoxFile_.fileType), "directory")
        )
    );

    TypedQuery<MyBoxFile> typedQuery = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    return typedQuery.getResultList();
}
```

My problem is that whenever I exceed 1 child of a directory I get this error:

`The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: <openjpa-2.3.0-nonfinal-1540826-r422266:1542644 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null`

And the error is at line `return typedQuery.getResultList();`

Persist and merge work just fine (I can persist a child of child, in the database it looks good, but with the criteriaQuery i get the error)

Does anyone see where could the problem come from ?
Thanks (I am literally getting crazy ! I did my best to write the question correctly indented, sorry if not looking good)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found the answer !!
In fact, the collections annotated `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` cause the framework to go into an infinite loop when trying to fetch a `MyBoxFile` with its parent and children (when fetching the parent it will try to fetch its children and then for each child try to fetch its children and its prents ... infinitely !).
The most unexpected solution is to add the `transient` keyword for each one of these collections (it was only luck which got me to try it).
I hope it will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that JPQL query would look like this:

```
SELECT mbf
FROM MyBoxFile mbf
WHERE mbf.fileType = 'directory' AND mbf.owner = :owner
```

then related criteria based query may look as follows:

```java
public static List<MyBoxFile> findAllUsersDirs(MyBoxUser owner,String fileType) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<MyBoxFile> cq = cb.createQuery(MyBoxFile.class);
    Root<MyBoxFile> mbf = cq.from(MyBoxFile.class);

    cq.select(mbf);
    cq.where(cb.and(
        cb.equal(mbf.get(MyBoxFile_.owner), cb.parameter(MyBoxUser.class, "p1")),
        cb.equal(mbf.get(MyBoxFile_.fileType), cb.parameter(String.class, "p2"))
    ));

    TypedQuery<MyBoxFile> q = em.createQuery(cq);
    q.setParameter("p1", owner);
    q.setParameter("p2", fileType);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

and finally the invocation:

```java
List<MyBoxFile> result = findAllUsersDirs(owner, "directory");
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Almost... at least you don't select anything in your query ;)

Comment: It's not required in the criteria query if I am selecting everything from the table ... Anyway, I still have the same problem

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the problem with EclipseLink, but the query works like a charm (with and without select). Did you try to use the latest stable release (OpenJPA 2.2.3) ?

Comment: Yes I am using the latest TomEE distribution, and it comes with OpenJPA, I searched a little if this is not handled with OpenJPA but nothing seems to be documented ...

Comment: Have you tried to execute the criteria query without `where` statement or one of its parameters? Or execute it in JavaSE (application-managed entity manager). Does querying data works with JPQL? Probably won't help but I am just trying to locate the root-cause. btw. I have slightly updated my proposal.

Comment: I tried with JPQL and it did the same behavior! Now I tried what you suggested and still ... same problem! I really don't understand the error: "PersistenceException: null"